# Problem happens when doing a cross join within table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am modifying my query to include pagination and rownum counts in it, but somehow the rownum is causing an error

> Ambigous column name

Code:

```
WITH List AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY error_type asc) AS rowNum,
        MAX(id) AS id, 
        COUNT(errorid) AS ecount,
        MAX(errorid) AS errorid,
        FORMAT(MAX(datein), 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt PST', 'en-US') AS max_datein,
        template,
        line,
        error_message, 
        UPPER(error_type) AS error_type 
    FROM
        mytable mt
    GROUP BY
        errorid,
        template, 
        line,
        error_message,
        error_type 
),
ListRecordCount AS
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        List,
        (
            SELECT 
                MAX(rowNum) AS TotalrecordCount
            FROM List
        ) AS TotalrecordCount
) 
SELECT *
FROM 
    ListRecordCount 
    INNER JOIN List mi ON mt.id = mi.id
WHERE rowNum BETWEEN 1 and 5000
ORDER BY mi.max_datein
```

Error I am getting is this:

> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "mt.id" could not be bound. (4104)
>   [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'rowNum'. (209)
>   [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'rowNum'. (209)

Comment: You must alias `ListRecordCount as mt` and specify `mt.rowNum`. And ` max(errorid)` is useless as you group by `errorid`. But why do you join those CTEs?

Comment: Now after your change, i get this: `> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'mt'. (102)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you first specify rowNum in List table, then you select * from List to create ListRecordCount table, which also includes column rowNum here. So if you join ListRecordCount with List, you will have rowNum in both tables, which causes ambiguous.

And also from your query above, I don't see a reason why you join these two tables.

I believe this query is what you are looking for.

```
WITH List AS(
    SELECT 
        row_number() over(ORDER BY error_type asc) AS rowNum
        , max(id) as id, count(errorid) as ecount
        , max(errorid) as errorid, FORMAT(max(datein), 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt PST', 'en-US') as max_datein
        , template,line,error_message, upper(error_type) AS error_type 
    from mytable mt
    group by errorid, template,line,error_message,error_type 
),
ListRecordCount AS(
    SELECT 
        *
        , (SELECT MAX(rowNum) AS TotalrecordCount FROM List) AS TotalrecordCount
    FROM List
)
SELECT *
FROM ListRecordCount 
WHERE rowNum BETWEEN 1 and 5000
order by max_datein
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `row_num` in both tables.  Perhaps you intend either:

```
    select . . .
    from ListRecordCount lrc join
         List mi 
         on mt.id = mi.id 
    where lrc.rowNum between 1 and 5000
```

or:

```
    select . . .
    from ListRecordCount lrc join
         List mi 
         on mt.id = mi.id 
    where mi.rowNum between 1 and 5000
```

Or, if you want the row number based on the result set:

```
select *
from (select . . ., row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from ListRecordCount lrc join
           List mi 
           on mt.id = mi.id 
     ) mil
where seqnum between 1 and 5000
```

Comment: your answer is very confusing and i tried the first two and seems not working, have not tried 3rd one because i don't understood that part, can you post a complete example

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to your main `SELECT` clause :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    ListRecordCount 
    INNER JOIN List mi ON mt.id = mi.id
WHERE rowNum BETWEEN 1 and 5000
                  ^^
```

The problem comes from the fact that both common table expressions `ListRecordCount` and `List` have a column called `rowNum` (more details later).

To solve this, all you need to do is prefix column `rowNum` in the main query. It has to be either `mt.rowNum` or `mi.rowNum`, for example :

```
...
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    ListRecordCount mt
    INNER JOIN List mi ON mt.id = mi.id
WHERE mt.rowNum BETWEEN 1 and 5000
ORDER BY mi.max_datein
```

Nb : looks like you were missing the declaration of the `mt` alias on `ListRecordCount`, I added it.

**Details**

`List` defines a `rowNum` column :

```
WITH List AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY error_type asc) AS rowNum,
    ...
```

`ListItems` does a `SELECT *` on `List` hence it also has column `rowNum` :

```
...
ListRecordCount AS
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        List,
    ...
```